# Socket.io with apache

Tags: apache, node.js, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I dont have much experience neither in Node.js not in socket.io, thus maybe I will ask silly questions and sorry for that first of all.

I am trying to do following:

1. Installed node on ubuntu where I have apache also installed.
2. Created virtual host in apache and set it as proxy to node. My conf file looks like:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin giorgi@omedia.ge
       ServerName node.aidemo.info
       ServerAlias www.node.aidemo.info

       ProxyRequests off
       <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
       </Proxy>

       <Location />
          ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
          ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
       </Location>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Have created simple js file for server (first server example in socket.io website) and started server from cli with command: node server.js.
   It starts perfectly and listens to 8080
4. Created another virtualhost where I put clientside index.html (also from first example in socket.io). At first I had problem (and actually main problem is this), browser couldn't resolve path /socket.io/socket.io.js. Then I went to the url (http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js) from lynx locally from terminal, downloaded that js and put locally with virtualhost near index.html. After this, browser could resolve that request, but I have error when socket.io.js itself is trying to get the url:

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1347623348836
   ```

Do you have any ideas how can I solve this problem?
My main goal is to have web url from which I can access my node server and talk with it with socket.io - for example to create very simple chat.

I hope I was clear.
Thank you everyone who will try to help.

Comment: probably duplicate with http://serverfault.com/questions/290121/configuring-apache2-to-proxy-websocket

Comment: dont think its a duplicate...
My question is about concrete problem: resolving requeest to socket.io.js file from apache

Answer (score 5):

I am using express + socket.io and they are listening on port `3001`. And I want `http://example.com/folder` to redirect to my Express app listening on port `3001` (i.e, to `http://localhost:3001`, **server-side**).

I have done the following.

The .html file has this:

```
<script src='/folder/socket.io/socket.io.js'> </script>  
<script>  
var socket = io.connect('http://example.com', {resource: 'folder/socket.io'});  
...  
</script>
```

And my apache2 conf looks like this:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /folder/ http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse /folder/ http://localhost:3001/

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /folder/>
    allow from all
</Location>
```

Note that it requires the module `proxy_http` to be enabled. To enable it, run this command:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http; service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I am getting a handshake fail with HTTP code 502 with this method, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `socket.io.js` file locally near your `index.html` file, it will not resolve the problem because you probably didn't change the url in your `socket` var in `main.js` file, look at:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

in your `main.js/index.html` (script)

replace with:

```
var socket = io.connect(httpprotocol+hostname+httpport);
```

My code source look like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('https://192.168.43.187:8443/');
```

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:8080` is obviously not going to be available to anything outside of your server.

The client-side javascript's `io.connect()` should be connecting to `http://node.aidemo.info` so that apache can send that off to Node.

`http://node.aidemo.info:8080` might also work if you've opened up port 8080.