# Node.js not executing properly with Apache Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

[image]This node.js code is running on my localhost but when i am running it on Apache server with mod_proxy and mod_http_proxy enabled it gives me the source code of the chatserver rather than executing it. I have modified my conf file so that it proxies every request to port 5000(for testing purpose).
Now I have 2 questions:
1)Why do I get the static chatserver page when I open localhost:5000?
2)Why do I get the source code of the chatserver when I open localhost?

**The chat
This is the virtual host configuration of Apache conf file.

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    ProxyPass  http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/
</Location>
```

This is my chatserver code:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
var fs = require('fs');

http.listen(5000);

function handler(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
       res.writeHead(500);
       return res.end('Error loading index.html');
      }

     ** res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});**
      res.end(data);
    }
  );
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('clientMessage', function(content) {
    socket.emit('serverMessage', 'You said: ' + content);
    socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', socket.id + ' said: ' + 
      content);
  });
});
```

This is my index file
index.html

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Node.js WebSocket chat</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          #input {
            width: 200px;
          }
          #messages {
            position: fixed;
            top: 40px;
            bottom: 8px;
            left: 8px;
            right: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
            padding: 8px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>

      <body>
    <h1> Your link to other page</h1>
    <a href = "http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
        Your message:
        <input type="text" id="input">

        <div id="messages"></div>

        <script src="http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var messagesElement = document.getElementById('messages');
          var lastMessageElement = null;

          function addMessage(message) {
            var newMessageElement = document.createElement('div');
            var newMessageText = document.createTextNode(message);

            newMessageElement.appendChild(newMessageText);
            messagesElement.insertBefore(newMessageElement, 
              lastMessageElement);
            lastMessageElement = newMessageElement;
          }

          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
          socket.on('serverMessage', function(content) {
            addMessage(content);
          });

          var inputElement = document.getElementById('input');

          inputElement.onkeydown = function(keyboardEvent) {
            if (keyboardEvent.keyCode === 13) {
              socket.emit('clientMessage', inputElement.value);
              inputElement.value = '';
              return false;
            } else {
              return true;
            }
          };
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: From what I read in the apache docs you only need the *ProxyPass* and *ProxyPassReverse* statements for a reverse proxy. Nothing more.

Comment: Can it be that you placed your javascript files into the public web directory?

Comment: @bodokaiser No my javascript files are not placed in public web directory.My chatserver is running as a separate entity on port 5000 and all my proxy requests are tunneled to the node server.So whenever I open the port 5000 i get the chatserver(though it is static,I mean you can't send any messages)and when I open without the port I get the source code.

Comment: @Bart Yes Even I have read the same and have tried to implement simple echo server through the same proxy setting and it worked like a charm,but whenever I try to execute my chatserver it does not work the intended way

Comment: Do you send a `Content-Type: text/html` header with Node.js? If you do, does Apache strip it?

Comment: **Alvaro G. Vicario** 
`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});`
adding this line does the trick.Now I am able to get the webpage but it is still not dynamic.I cant use the webpage to send messages in the browser.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a very useful description. Does `http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js` load successfully? Does your code trigger errors? Did you write this code or its someone else's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Socket.io with apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424707/socket-io-with-apache)